# Regex sometimes returning null in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

While using regex to match values inside of a formula string I found this issue that regex would return null even though there is a match.

```js
var formula = "round((DATAtotal_sq_ft * .6) + (QTY16 * 4) + (QTY17 * 2) + QTY18 + QTY15 + QTY12 * 18 / 3000, 1)";

const qtyRegex = /(QTY)(\d*)|(LEN)(\d*)|(DATA)([a-zA-Z_-|\d]*)/gm;
let m;

while ((m = qtyRegex.exec(formula)) !== null) {
  var val = 0; // Here is irrelevant code that gets the value
  formula = formula.replace(m[0], val);
}
console.log(formula);
```

In the above snippet you can see the result that a couple of the values don't get replaced but at the same time all of them get detected by 
regex101 https://regex101.com/r/WTpvFq/1. For some reason I cant seem to narrow down what I'm doing wrong even after reading a number of different answers to similar problems.

I could use a workaround and use `formula.match(qtyRegex)` but I am really certain it's just an error in the Regex so I'd prefer properly fixing it instead of plastering it with a patch.

Comment: Using `.replace` inside an `.exec` loop does not look appropriate. What are you really doing? Besides, `[a-zA-Z_-|\d]` is an error, probably you wanted to use `[\w-]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a while loop you can directly replace using the RegExp with the `replacer` callback of [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) like this:

```
formula = formula.replace(qtyRegex, replacer)

// take a look at the docs I've linked above for an explanation of these params
function replacer(match, p1, p2, ..., offset, string) {
  let calculatedValue = 0 // perform your irrelevant code that gets the value here
  return calculatedValue
}
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the replacer can be a function, and that's where the manipulation should be, I'll update the answer for clarification.

Comment: Just to clarify. Each QTY[number] is a string representing a different quantity in a list of items. So I don't want to replace all of the matches with the same value. That's why I opted to replace with string in a loop

Comment: @wp78de The `replacer` callback alternative was created with this exact intent

Comment: @TrevorReimer Using a while is a bit dirty in my eyes, as the alternative's pretty simple, but who am I to judge I guess.

Comment: @GMaiolo I see your point now. I got it working but i'll definitely try and improve it with your tips

Comment: @TrevorReimer if you get it to work with this you can change the accepted answer :)

Comment: Well it certainly works. Learn a little something new everyday I guess

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `g` modifier in a regexp, it remembers the position in the string where it last matched, and subsequent matches start from that position. But your code is replacing the match with a shorter string, so the remembered position may be past the beginning of the next match, and it doesn't find it.

Get rid of the `g` modifier and it will search from the beginning each time.

```js
var formula = "round((DATAtotal_sq_ft * .6) + (QTY16 * 4) + (QTY17 * 2) + QTY18 + QTY15 + QTY12 * 18 / 3000, 1)";

const qtyRegex = /(QTY)(\d*)|(LEN)(\d*)|(DATA)([a-zA-Z_-|\d]*)/m;
let m;

while ((m = qtyRegex.exec(formula)) !== null) {
  var val = 0; // Here is irrelevant code that gets the value
  formula = formula.replace(m[0], val);
}
console.log(formula);
```